# Dockerfile execution permission denied

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I have this dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN set -x && \
    apk add --no-cache \
              openrc \
              bash \
              libreswan \
              xl2tpd \
              ppp \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/pluto \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/xl2tpd \
    && touch /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
COPY ipsec.conf /etc/ipsec.conf
COPY ipsec.secrets /etc/ipsec.secrets
COPY xl2tpd.conf /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf
COPY options.l2tpd.client /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
COPY startup.sh /
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/startup.sh"]

CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

When I run that in local everything works ok. but I'm trying to execute the image generated in a gcp vm (ubuntu) and I get the following error

```
/bin/sh: can't open './startup.sh': Permission denied
```

Can someone help me with this error?

note: I also tried to modify permissions with:

```
RUN ["chmod", "777", "/startup.sh"]
RUN chmod +x /startup.sh
RUN chmod 777 /startup.sh
```

And execute the script with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]
RUN ["./startup.sh"]
RUN ./startup.sh
```

Comment: You need to create a user first and then using that user you can perform this actions

Comment: Did you try giving +x permission in host machine itself?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing here to add user to change permission
[More Info](https://dev.to/nownabe/secure-user-in-docker-1b5m)

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash  myuser
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this add these lines in your docker file.

```
RUN chown -R admin:admin /
RUN chmod 755 /
```

Just give the Admin rights to `/` root directory.

and your docker file will look like this

```
FROM alpine:3.8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN set -x && \
    apk add --no-cache \
              openrc \
              bash \
              libreswan \
              xl2tpd \
              ppp \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/pluto \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/xl2tpd \
    && touch /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
COPY ipsec.conf /etc/ipsec.conf
COPY ipsec.secrets /etc/ipsec.secrets
COPY xl2tpd.conf /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf
COPY options.l2tpd.client /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
COPY startup.sh /
RUN chown -R admin:admin /
RUN chmod 755 /
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```